# How and when are the PHPSESID and the server record of that session deleted?

Tags: php, session

We know that when the browser window closes, the session ends, and the browser deletes the phpsesid from our computer. But server side, how do we know that we need to deleted the record of that PHPSESID? Since we do not know when the user closes his/her browser window. I mean can somebody set the browser so that on closes the phpsesid is never deleted and thus it can be always logged in?
Or how does this work?

Comment: Use web-socket   when your user closes the browser, the connection will be interrupted and you unset session at server

Comment: I'm indeed asking the question, what happens if we do not something like this? If we do not keep persistent connection with the user. And do you think it is difficult to trick the server that our browser window never closes?

Comment: On Linux servers sessions are typically saved in temporary folders and thus got auto-deleted periodically.

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini file you will see that there is a lot of variables used to configure PHP sessions. 
`session.gc_maxlifetime` is used to set the time before the session expire as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).
As soon as this delay is expired on the server, the garbage collector will delete the file corresponding to the session.
This is independent from the client's side cookie duration which is set by `session.cookie_lifetime`.

Some info about the [garbage collection](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php).

Comment: It says 1440. So after 24 minutes the record is deleted from the temp folder of php? Even though the user is logged in for 24 minutes? Or after 24 minutes that record was lastly used?

Comment: the user will be logged in for 1440s. It is very short, I think that frequently websites use longer duration, like months, but regenerate frequently the session ID and client cookie, to prevent any hacking.

Comment: Wait, you mean that if I'm persistently browsing a website for 24 minutes it'll log me out after 24 minutes? Will it not instead delete it after 24 minutes of inactivity of that session record?

Comment: sorry, my bad, it's counted from the last activity of the session (calling session_start() for example). So you will have a session duration of activity+1440s by default (but you can either modify this value or use another session handler, using a database for example)